# Resize image according to the page scale

Tags: html, image

When I change the scale of the current page using "ctrl & +" or "ctrl & -", I want my image ('img' tag) to change its size accordingly.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vh & vw units for your Image in css.

```
img{
width:50vh;
height:50vh;
/* your css*/
}
```

more details on css [units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to set the width of the image to 100%;

Or you can use media queries.

More about media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp